# date time conversion problem when inserting data into sql database

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker, datetime

I used to query:

```
Dim a As String
a = "INSERT INTO tblVisitor(Name, Sex, TimeIn, EnterDate)
     VALUES('"& txtName.Text &"', '"& cboSex.Text &"', '"& Now() &"', '"& DateTime.Parse(cboEnterDate.Text) &"')"

myCommand = New SqlCommand(a, myConnection)
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
........................................
```

Which cboEnterDate is my DateTime Picker. Then I got the message:

```
Conversion failed when converting date time from character string.
```

Please help.

Comment: Please check with debugger the value of 'a'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By constructing a string, you a) open yourself to SQL injection, and b) end up converting strings to datetimes to strings to datetimes.

If, instead, you use parameters:

```
Dim a As String
a = "INSERT INTO tblVisitor(Name, Sex, TimeIn, EnterDate)
     VALUES(@Name, @Sex, @TimeIn, @EnterDate)"

myCommand = New SqlCommand(a, myConnection)
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",txtName.Text)
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sex",cboSex.Text)
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeIn",DateTime.Now)
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EnterDate",DateTime.Parse(cboEnterDate.Text))
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Which only performs a single conversion of string to datetime. Although, if `cboEnterDate` is a [DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx), you can avoid treating it as a string at all:

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EnterDate",cboEnterDate.Value)
```

Comment: thanks guy, it works. Thanks for this tip, I now understand what is sql injection.

Answer (score 2):

Look up using SQL Parameters. The code you are using now is not only prone to parsing issues w/r/t date formats, it is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Creating SQL statements via string concatenation is just a really, really bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Change Now() to Now.ToShortTimeString  That should fix the problem.

Edit:  Oops and the DateTime.Parse(cboEnterDate.Text) add .ToShortDate to the end.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `DateTime.Parse(cboEnterDate.Text)` it parses the string into a datetime object. You should send the string `cboEnterDate.Text` directly and let the SQL server do the parsing

Comment: I disagree - keep (or convert) to a datetime value as soon as possible, and trust the data access libraries to deal with any necessary conversions between datetime representations.