# VB.Net Inserting DateTimePicker to MS Access Database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Good day to everyone here at stackoverflow! I have a simple question that maybe you guys could help me out with. I created a prototype for inserting a DateTimePicker into the MS Access database. I followed this guide:
[date time conversion problem when inserting data into sql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530536/date-time-conversion-problem-when-inserting-data-into-sql-database) and although it helped the person asking the question, it did not help me at all :(

This is the picture and this is my code. This is just a simple prototype that if solved, I will be able to implement it into the actual system I am working on with my classmates.

[image: Inserting datetimepicker]

There is a syntax error apparently. But if I remove just the datetimepicker codes I can insert my last name without any problems and have it show up in MS Access. These are the codes.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Dim conString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Israel De Leon\Documents\dateinsert.accdb;"
    Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(conString)
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim adapter As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ListView1.View = View.Details
        ListView1.FullRowSelect = True

        ListView1.Columns.Add("Last Name", 100)
        ListView1.Columns.Add("Date", 100)
    End Sub

    Public Sub add()
        Dim SQL As String = "INSERT INTO Table1(LastName, Time) VALUES (@LastName, @Time)"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(SQL, con)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", TextBox1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", DateTime.Parse(DateTimePicker1.Value))

        'OPEN CONNECTION AND INSERT
        Try
            con.Open()

            If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 Then
                MsgBox("Succesfully Inserted")

            End If

            con.Close()


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            con.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        add()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Please help this mate out. Thank you :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the name of the column Time. Time is a reserved word in MS-Access. You need to put square brackets around that name

```
Dim SQL As String = "INSERT INTO Table1(LastName, [Time]) VALUES (@LastName, @Time)"
```

I also strongly suggest you to [not use AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), but the more precise Add where you can properly set the datatype of your parameter and avoid the hidden code of AddWithValue that translates your inputs to the expected ones

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", OleDbType.VarWChar, 100).Value = TextBox1.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Time", OleDbType.DateTime).Value =DateTimePicker1.Value
```

Notice that the Add method allows you to define also the size of your data in case of text. This allows the database engine to optimize your insert query. (Not sure if this happens also with access but surely with Sql Server this is an important optimization)

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `monthCalendar` control:

```
textBox1.Text = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.Date.ToShortDateString()
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", textBox1.Text)
```